# Creating HTML Controls as classes in Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, oop, javascript

Are there any JavaScript tutorial(s) which guides the creation of HTML controls as classes and using them across html pages?

I've done enough searching in internet which didn't yield any result. My apologies for posting such a newbie question.

Comment: You'll have to explain that a lot better. What exactly is "HTML control as classes" ?

Comment: You might want to look into [Google Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/), but to a significant extent there's not really a satisfying and practical way to do what you're asking today.

Comment: For e.g, Lets take a <input type="text"> Can I have this as a class defined in some JS file like "TextBox" and can use it as var myTextBox = new TextBox(); ??

Comment: No. Html is a little more detailed then that. To mess with HTML elements like, div, text boxes and such, you'll need to research html document.

Comment: @DavidR - You can do that, but you'll need to write the classes yourself to match mfc or qt kind of abstraction you are looking for.

Comment: Well, if you want that specific functionality you'll need to look into javascript oop.

Comment: Can someone provide me some links/books/tutorials if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really specific in your question but I will try to point you in some directions that I assume may be helpfull:

1. **Polymer** http://www.polymer-project.org/

   A Framework to write reusable *Web Components*. For example a "Controlls" component which can be dropped into your HTML code wherever you need it just by writing `<custom-controlls></custom-controlls>`
2. **Virtual DOM** https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom

   An implementation of the DOM in javascript.

I think the first oneis more likely to be the right for your use case.

Comment: Polymer looks the best fit for my requirement. Thanks a lot Oliver!.

Answer (score 0):

You can do. Declare the input variable in your javascript file. and use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var textbox = document.createElement('input');

var button = document.createElement('input');

    $('.first-name').html(textbox);
    $('.first-name').find('input').attr({'id': 'first-name', 'type': 'text'});

    $('.button-div').html(button);
    $('.button-div').find('input').attr({'id': 'save', 'type': 'button'}).val('Save');
});


<body>
  <div class="first-name"> </div>

  <div class="button-div"> </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** This will be very complex

Comment: [document.createElement(tagName);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

Comment: Is this ok now: Jonathan

Comment: Thanks Aman!.. Although this contributes to a great extent to my requirement, I still believe opting a framework like "Polymer" is a wise thing to do.

Thanks for your time!